# How to control bones of Cloth in C# using kinect and unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, blender, virtual-reality, kinect-v2

I am working on a application similar to Virtual Dressing room. I want to map bones of cloth with bones of Model. I have bones of Model but unable to fetch bones from Cloth (GameObject). I have tried following things:

```
//go is GameObject 
go.GetComponent<SkinnedMeshRenderer>().bones;
```

I am  using Unity3D 2017 version. And C# for programming. Also I am using kinect to capture movement. I have created 3D cloth using Blender and exported in .fbx format along with bones. Anyone please help on this. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Have a look on this asset. https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/kinect-with-ms-sdk-7747

Comment: I have Checked this. But this is not much useful. Because the it animates Model itself, Instead of applying any cloth on Model.

Comment: you need replace the avatar in the current model and map Kinect capture data to your model

Comment: Actually I am new to Kinect, Unity and C# as well. It would be really great if you mention one small snippet which can help me in achieving this. thanks :)